# HTTPS cluster markers and custom styles

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-markers

I have a secure site that is using MarketCusterer for clustering markers!  When viewing the page, I was getting the view only secure bits or see them all as I understand the icons are stored on a non-secure site.

I've located the icons, included in my ASP.NET MVC project and setup the necessary routes to allow access to the images.  My problem is, once I add the styles (code below), nothing is displayed.  I moved the images out of the MVC site onto our corporate public site and ensured I could get to the URL and still nothing was displayed.  When I zoomed out far enough for the fourth image to be displayed, the standard google one appeared.

Having stepped through the code debugging, I can see my styles are being passed through correctly to the markerclusterer.js as expected.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks
Simon

```
            var clusterStyles = [
                {
                    opt_textColor: 'black',
                    url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/images/m1.png'
                },
                {
                    opt_textColor: 'black',
                    url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/images/m2.png'
                 },
                 {
                    opt_textColor: 'black',
                    url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com//images/m3.png'
                 }
                ];

            var mcOptions = { styles: clusterStyles };

            var markers = [];
    Loop to add markers

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Chrome is very strict about cross-protocol issues, so make sure all content is loaded either via http or https. Also, note the double slash in `m3.png`.

Comment: Hi, mainly IE but the whole point is trying to ensure all comms are via HTTPS to avoid the question whether to show unsecure info.  The URL above is actually HTTPS in my code and this was just to check it wasn't a problem viewing HTTPS on my static corporate site...

Comment: Also Orique, double slash is just me cutting and pasting out our website address - sorry :)

Comment: I'm unable to help you since I have almost no experience with Google Maps -- however I wanted to point out those tiny details just to make sure they weren't involved in the problem.

Comment: var clusterStyles = [
{
opt_textColor: 'black',
url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/images/m1.png'
},
{
opt_textColor: 'black',
url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/images/m2.png'
},
{
opt_textColor: 'black',
url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/images/m3.png'
}
];
var mcOptions = { styles: clusterStyles };
var markers = [];
Loop to add markers
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);

Comment: What I'm unsure of here is whether it's MVC stopping the direct route of my icons (although assuming as it's using the google-maps-api, it's probably that component that's trying to access my icons) or whether there's a problem locating them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested it appears it was because the height and width values were missing.  I had thought these were optional parameters but it seems they need to be there!

hHanks for looking.

Simon